# Is submodule a correct approach for this GUI problem?

Tags: java, git, github, javafx, git-submodules

I'm developing a simple study compiler in Java. The application also needs a GUI and I'm using javaFX for this purpose. However, I don't know how to proper wrap the two things together.

I added the [compiler github repository](https://github.com/Leonardo-Rocha/Xpp-Compiler) as a submodule of the [GUI repo](https://github.com/Leonardo-Rocha/XPP-Compiler-GUI).

I want to be able to call the Xpp-Compiler-Main class and pass a command-line argument(in this case a file that was read on the GUI) in this method of the GUI(src/sample/SampleController.java : line 80):

```java
public void actionCompileProgram(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        System.out.println("Compiling...");
        //something like this:
        Xpp-Compiler.Main(currentFile.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

How do I "import" the submodule and call the main method of the Xpp-Compiler main class?
Is there a better way to wrap those things together?

Comment: Won't a regular dependency work here? Are you using Maven? Gradle? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is submodule a correct approach for this GUI problem?

Only if you need the sources of the submodule for the main project to work.
A [Maven approach](https://maven.apache.org/) can help.
That means, you would generally define a [multi-module `pom.xml`](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-multi-module) in order for your main project to:

- compile and [install locally (in the maven cache)](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html) your submodule content
- compile itself (which would work, because it would declare in its own `pom.xml`a dependency to the submodule jar, which was just compiled and installed first)

Comment: Yes, I need the sourcers of the submodule for the main project to work. I'll try this out!